# Trying to understand the Swagger UI integration in JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, swagger-ui

I do not understand how the Swagger UI integration is done in JHipster because when I copy/paste the code to put it in a different application, it does not work.

In the `navbar.component.html`, when clicking on the API menu, it invokes the router with the `docs` route:

```
<li *ngIf="swaggerEnabled">
    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="docs" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.admin.apidocs">API</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The `docs` route invokes the `SpnDocsComponent`

```
export const docsRoute: Route = {
    path: 'docs',component: SpnDocsComponent
};
```

And the `docs.component.html` just iframes the `swagger-ui/index.html` page

```
<iframe src="swagger-ui/index.html" width="100%" height="900" seamless
    target="_top" title="Swagger UI" class="border-0"></iframe>
```

Once I've copied all the code above, paste it in a non-JHipster application, I get an error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'swagger-ui'
```

That's because the Angular router intercepts the `swagger-ui/index.html` call and looks for a `swagger-ui` route (which does not exist).

How does this work in JHipster ? Is there a particular configuration for telling the router not to intercept this call ?

Comment: @shockey pointed this really nice Swagger UI integration in Angular that he made : https://github.com/shockey/swagger-ui-angular4

Comment: Are you using html5 mode or hashbang for url scheme in your app?